# Indexing EAV model using Solr

Tags: solr, entity-attribute-value

The database I have at hand uses the EAV model describing all objects one can find in a house. Good or bad isn't the question, there is no choice but to keep and use this model. 6.000+ items point to 3.000+ attributes and 150.000+ attribute-values.
My task is to get this data into a Solr index for quick searching/sorting/faceting.

In Solr, using DIH, a regular SQL query is used to extract data. Each column name returned from the query is a 'field' (defined or not in a schema), and each row of the query's resultset is a 'document'.

Because the EAV model uses rows for attributes instead of columns, a simple query will not work, I need to flatten each item row. What should my SQL query look like in order to extract all items from the DB ? Is there a special Solr/DIH configuration which I should consider ?

There are some similar questions on SO, but none really helped.
Any pointers are much appreciated!

Comment: Having sub entities that extract the rows and using a TemplateTransformer to use one column as part of the field name should work. However, I'd recommend writing the indexing solution yourself (i.e. retrieve rows from the DB, reformat as a Solr document and send it to Solr) to get better performance. The DIH support has been removed from the Solr core as of Solr 9 and is now only supported externally (which might not be an issue, but DIH is limited to a single node for example)

Comment: @MatsLindh. Thank you for your comment. I can easily create a 'flat' object using a SQL query/SP/whatever, and turn that into a JSON thingy, but that would work for a single object at a time. I would have to post each object one by one into Solr. Is that what you suggest ?

Comment: Correct; you can batch updates and submit 1000 or 10000 (or any other number, really) documents at once before committing (and since you only have 6k docs, it should be rather quick). It'll usually be far more performant and flexible than using DIH. Don't create arbitrary JSON, but use a Solr client that maps everything to the expected format for Solr update messages.

Comment: @MatsLindh. Thanks again. Why not create JSON documents out of the flattened records ? Why do you think using a Solr client would be best ?

Comment: The Solr client will allow you to easily batch the updates and send them in the format most optimized for your structure (for example if you're using Java it'll use javabin). It'll also avoid having to manually create JSON and then submitting does documents through a different feature. Using a Solr client allows you to integrate it into the regular flow in your application; sending an update each time an object is updated, instead of at regular intervals.

Comment: @MatsLindh. Thanks a lot for your help.